# anchor deploy with Ledger Nano S

Tags: anchor, solana-program, ledger

I am trying to deploy program with `anchor deploy` and getting the following error.

```
Deploying workspace: https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com
Upgrade authority: usb://ledger
Deploying program "lpfi-buyback-program"...
Program path: /Users/aperire0402/lpfi-buyback-program/target/deploy/lpfi_buyback_program.so...
Error: Dynamic program error: protocol error: Unknown error
There was a problem deploying: Output { status: ExitStatus(unix_wait_status(256)), stdout: "", stderr: "" }.
```

Is it possible to anchor deploy with ledger?

Answer (score 1):

My bad, ledger password was not entered :_